# Counting and Summing three tables together and get users information with their like counts

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have three tables:

1. **table**: users / **columns:** user_id, email, username
2. **table**: activities / **columns:** object, type, like_count
3. **table**: activities2 / **columns:**  object, target_type, subject, type

The like_count in activities table has no problem and I count all of that with this query:

```
SELECT SUM(activities.like_count) AS likes, users.user_id, users.email, users.username
FROM activities
INNER JOIN users
ON activities.subject = users.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
```

But there is another count in activities table which is being inserted(NOT UPDATED) each time some other types of posts liked and I counted them by this query:

```
SELECT activities.subject, activities.object, COUNT(activities.type) AS likes
FROM activities
INNER JOIN activities2
ON activities.object = activities2.object AND activities2.target_type = 'parent'
WHERE activities2.type LIKE 'like_%'
GROUP BY activities2.subject
```

BUT the problem starts from here when I want to join them together! I want to count `like_count` + count of likes that inserted in that table(activities2) that contains string of 'like_' and beside this I want to join the subject(in activities table) which is related to user_id in the other table(users).

My last query is this:

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.email, users.username, activities.object, COUNT(activities.type)+SUM(activities.like_count) AS likes
FROM activities
INNER JOIN activities2
ON activities.object = activities2.object AND activities2.target_type = 'parent'
INNER JOIN users
ON activities.subject = users.user_id
WHERE activities2.type LIKE 'like_%'
GROUP BY users.user_id
```

The problem is when joining, it fetches the user information not for the one that I want.
In conclusion I want something like this:

```
user_id------email-----------------username----------object-------likes
2521---------a@b.com---------------abc---------------9578---------3
5484---------c@d.com---------------def---------------8547---------16
8431---------e@f.com---------------ghi---------------4584---------1
```

And offcourse the result is this but only likes are correct however columns of user_id, email, username that are in users table NOT!

I was wondering if you would help to fix it. I'm really tired of trying and facing to no result :(

users table data:

```
user_id-------------email---------------username
1-------------------a@b.com-------------abc
2-------------------c@d.com-------------def
3-------------------e@f.com-------------ghi
```

activities table data:

```
object----------type----------------like_count------subject
20--------------like_video----------0---------------1
20--------------like_photo----------0---------------2
33--------------like_music----------0---------------3
33--------------some_other_type-----5---------------6
33--------------some_other_type-----8---------------10
```

activities2 table data:

```
object------target_type-----subject-----type
20----------parent----------30----------like_video
21----------owner-----------40----------like_audio
22----------parent----------50----------something_not_start_with_like_
```

I want:

```
user_id------email-----------------username----------object-------likes
1------------a@b.com---------------abc---------------9578---------(sum of like_count + count of type which has like_ in first characters)
2------------c@d.com---------------def---------------8547---------(sum of like_count + count of type which has like_ in first characters)
3------------e@f.com---------------ghi---------------4584---------(sum of like_count + count of type which has like_ in first characters)
```

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. It will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), or return an unpredictable result on older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Well formatted text.)

Comment: I see no relations... How do you know which user has which activities?

Comment: @jarlh subject in activities and user_id in users are related.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, have consistent column names! I'd chose user_id for user id's. (The column name subject for user id's is very confusing.)

Comment: @jarlh What can I do? It has created just like that? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining the aggregate queries using derived tables and then run your addition calculation in the outer query. Also, below *object* column is removed from the second aggregate query's `GROUP BY` clause but still used in `JOIN` since you need summation at the *subject* level.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, u.username, a.`object`, u.likes + a.likes as `total_likes`
FROM
   (SELECT SUM(activities.like_count) AS likes, users.user_id, users.email, users.username
    FROM activities
    INNER JOIN users
    ON activities.subject = users.user_id
    GROUP BY user_id, users.email, users.username) u

INNER JOIN
   (SELECT activities.subject, COUNT(activities.type) AS  likes
    FROM activities
    INNER JOIN activities2
    ON activities.object = activities2.object AND activities2.target_type = 'parent'
    WHERE activities2.type LIKE 'like_%'
    GROUP BY activities2.subject) As a

ON u.user_id = a.subject
```

Comment: I really appreciate dear Parfait, although that wasn't the answer but helped me a lot :D

Comment: Glad I could help. This solution is an ANSI-compliant query with proper `GROUP BY` clauses. So does not exactly align to your original. Adjust accordingly.